# How to copy a file to another location for later use (java)

Tags: java, file

I am using this code

```
JFileChooser jf=new JFileChooser();
File f=jf.getSelectedFile();
name=f.getName();
```

I get the name of the file that I have chosen. In the project that I am doing I need to access this attached file again. I couldn't copy the original path. I want to know if I can copy the file to another location (the contents of the file- file being a .txt file) after it is attached, so that I can access the same for later use.

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you copy the original path?

Comment: Do you want the path to the file or a copy of the file on another folder? Path to file will be f.getAbsolutePath() read the API of File http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy file using `Files` class

```
Files.copy(f.toPath(), dest.toPath());
```

or

You can use Apache Commons IO lib to copy

```
FileUtils.copyFile(File source, File dest);
```

Comment: he is havin a file object!

Comment: he can get the path too dear

Comment: How can I get the path? Can you specify the code please.

Comment: @Niks would try that.